# Bash script to create 10 folders with a text file with current date in each file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I need a bash script that will

1) create 10 folders named from 1 to 10

2) create a .txt file with a name that corresponds to the current folder (e.g. `1` folder should have a `1.txt` file in it)

3) Each .txt file should contain current date and time inside it

I have written a bash script that is supposed to do the first two tasks, but for some reason I have an error. I have no idea how to implement the third point. Please help!

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do 
   mkdir "$i" 
done
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d) do
   touch "$dir"/name_date.txt
done
```

Comment: `for i in $(seq 1 10); do mkdir $i && date > $i/$i.txt; done`

Comment: date=$(stat -c ""%x"" FILENAME) 
echo ${date\%%.*}

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Rob answer :

```
for i in {1..10}; do mkdir $i && date > $i/$i.txt; done
```

Comment: @janos, this is generally a good practice indeed. Here, as we control the arguments, it is not vital.